# Angular form's button can not be pressed

Tags: c#, angular, forms, payment

I have a simple form for payment:

```
   <form method="POST" action="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <input  name="data" value="{{data}}" />
       <input  name="signature" value="{{signature}}" />
       <input type="image" src="//static.liqpay.ua/buttons/p1ru.radius.png" />
   </form>
```

The problem is that I can't press the button for payment, it's just don't work
[image]

I can assure you that the form is working I've checked this on C# with some changes:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="data" value="@ViewData["PaymentData"]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="@ViewData["Signature"]" />
        <input type="image" src="//static.liqpay.ua/buttons/p1ru.radius.png" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And all the parametress a passed correctly. It seems like Angular dont let me go to the link or sth like that. Help pls.

*UPDATE*

Ok I changed the form like this:

```
   <form [formGroup]="payForm" (ngSubmit)="LiqPay()" #formDir="ngForm"  novalidate>
      <input formControlName="data" name="data" value="{{data}}" />
      <input formControlName="signature" name="signature" value="{{signature}}" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout">go</button>
   </form>
```

with LiqPay method:

```
  LiqPay(){
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      this.payForm.value.data = this.data;
      this.payForm.value.signature = this.signature;
      this._http.post('https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout', 
      this.payForm,{headers}).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Now I guess the request is sent but it doesn't redirect on the desired link (https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout). So how can I change the form to redirect to this link with post data?

Comment: I can not see that you have used any angularjs features here.  Have you used ngSubmit event on the form. Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: @shana so how should I correct my form to look like Angular form? I can't see how can I pass the form to the specific url. ngSubmit works onlt on fucntions as I understand

Comment: @georgeawg I've updated the post maybe it will look more clear now

Comment: Box and banana syntax are part of Angular 2+ syntax, not AngularJS. The `LiqPay` function uses Angular 2+ methods.

Answer (score 1):

In the LiqPay method you are trying to send a post request to https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout. And in the button you have a ng-href attribute (trying to browser go to that url). I think that is not correct. You are sendind an asynchronous requets, and simultaneously sendind your user to that url.

I can understand, you are sending a form to a payment checkout? ok, you can use action in the form, exactly like the C# example.

I have tested your initial code

```
<form method="POST" action="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <input  name="data" value="{{data}}" />
       <input  name="signature" value="{{signature}}" />
       <input type="image" src="//static.liqpay.ua/buttons/p1ru.radius.png" />
</form>
```

And it works...
You can view it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/L1ruajzn/